# Make Laravel request from array with objects

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation, laravel-5, request

I have an array that makes in front end with js and pass that to my controller with ajax.

Ajax:

```
var values = [{FirstName: "fff"},{LastName: null}]
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/api/store-step",
    data: { values: values, step: activePanelNum }
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error,result) {
       console.log(jqXHR.responseJSON.errors);
    }).done(function( result ) {
       console.log(result);
    });
```

structure of array is this:

```
[{FirstName: "fff"},{LastName: null}]
```

Controller:

```
public function storeSteps(Request $request)
{     
    $validator = Validator::make($request->values, [
       'FirstName' => 'required',
       'LastName' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
       return response()->json(['success'=>false, 'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()],422);
        }
}
```

I can't validate this array with request validation Laravel. Now I'm going to turn this array into a Larval request to apply the rules to it.

Can any one helps?

Answer (score 7):

you can validate array element like this

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'values' => 'required',
            'values.*.FirstName' => 'required',
            'values.*.lastName' => 'required','
        ]);
```

by using `.` you can access an index in a array and `*` apples all indexes in the array.

Comment: in addition to this above, you might need to ```json_decode()``` that array first.

Comment: what is array_name here?

Comment: @MohammadHosseini you need to passe you array in a name that what I meant by that. `array_name : [{FirstName: "fff"}, {LastName: null} ]`

Comment: Here I don't have ````$maked_laravel_request_from_array```` I want to create that

Comment: can you update the question and add a die and dump on `$maked_laravel_request_from_array`

Comment: I update question and explain Clearer my problem. I want to make laravel request from array....means from ````$request->values````

Comment: @MohammadHosseini I've update my answer try that out

Comment: Each rule applies to all array objects. What do you think if I use static index instead of *? For example: 'values.0.FirstName' => 'required', 'values.1.LastName' => 'required'  . But the code is not clean. Do you think there is a better way?

Comment: if you are sure you only get only one index then sure it's ok!